# In django, how can i upload file via url?

Tags: django, url

Hi i'm making my own webserver using django.
i just want to upload local file to django server.
i google every method but i can't get answer.
every method using form or html but i don't want to using form and html
example : from www.localfolder/example.txt to /media/examplefolder.
i don't know how to do.. any help?
this is my code.

```
@csrf_exempt
def download_file(request, file):
    fl_path = 'media/'
    filename = str(file)
    fl = open(fl_path, 'r')
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(fl_path)
    response = HttpResponse(fl, content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename = %s" % filename
    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

What did you search for when you googled? These were the top 2 results for `Django files`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/files/

Seems to have everything you are looking for.